Remove customers from journey in case they placed an order within the wait activities of 6h or 24h
In journeybuilder, we want to build an abandoned basket journey.
We want to send out and email after 6h and after 20h.
Before each send we want to check if the customer bought something after the wait period and if so, the mail should not be send.
We have tried this with an exit criteria but you can't choose hours, only days.
We also want to avoid using the RaiseError() function in AMPscript but it seems to be harder than expected to find a solution here. What are we missing?

I didn't understand why Exit Criteria doesn't work for you - you can set it to check if the customer made an order and that can be the trigger to get the customer out of the Journey, right?

I think you can use wait until activity which wait for a duration, but also wait for an events. if the event was received, the contact go to another path, such as exit.  Wait until event is similar to API event.
